# Creating buttons in loop need different id for each

Tags: flash, actionscript, action

I'm trying to make dynamic menu using xml data, I'm creating that menu using loops 
Here is my code

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < iloscWpisow; i++)
        {
            _guzik=new guzikIK();
            _guzik.guzikIK_Over.alpha=0;

            _guzikTekst = new TextField();
            _guzikTekst.x = _tekstX;
            _guzikTekst.y = _tekstY;
            _guzikTekst.selectable = false;
            _guzikTekst.width = _tekstSzerokosc;
            _guzikTekst.height = _tekstWysokosc;
            /*_guzikTekst.embedFonts = true;*/
            tekst.color = 0xFFFFFF;
            /*tekst.font = _arialRounded.fontName;*/
            tekst.size = 18;
            _guzikTekst.defaultTextFormat = tekst;

            _guzikTekst.text = xml.children()[i]. tytul;

            _guzik.addChild(_guzikTekst);

            _guzik.x=32;
            _guzik.y=_tekstPolozenie*i+55;

            _guzik.buttonMode=true;
            _guzik.mouseChildren = false;
            _guzik[id]=i;
            _menu.addChild(_guzik);
            _guzik.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, klik);
```

And the problem is each button has the same id at the end, i need different id's for each butt so it can be recoginzed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to tell what exactly you're asking, but the approach I would take would be to store all your buttons in an array and then refer to the buttons by their index in the array. Something like:

```
var buttons:Array = [];
buttons.push(new Button());
buttons[0].buttonMode = true;
```

Comment: Also note that knowing the id of a dynamically generated Button doesn't do anything for you--it does not give you a handle to the instance.

Comment: thanks, i figured tahtone by myself, but that was the solution i was looking for :)